# Грамматически правильное продолжение предложения: "Выйдя из дома, ..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

Выйдя из дома,
1) начался сильный дождь.
2) повеяло сыростью.
3) мне нужно было торопиться.
4)я решил подождать отца.

Comment: А сама Света что предпочитает?

Comment: @Света, это простое школьное задание, можно и самой сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Вы найдёте, если поищете среди вариантов того, кто мог "выйти из дома" или то, что могло бы "выйти из дома".

**P.S.** Наводящий вопрос: могло ли "мне" само выйти из дома?

Comment: Оно повеяло сыростью, выйдя из дома... Как страшно жить!

Comment: К счастью, "оно" как таковое пока не проявляется :)

Comment: Кто-нибудь сможет пояснить мне суть вопроса, а то до меня она так и не доходит?

Comment: Суть вопроса - в совместимости деепричастного оборота с основной частью предложения (у них должен быть общий производитель действия). Здесь проходит только вариант 4. Остальные в разной степени близки к классическому нонсенсу "подъезжая к станции, у меня слетела шляпа".